# Removing a row from a table with VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

In Vue how do you remove a row from a table when the item is deleted?

Below is how I am rendering the table

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in items">
    <td v-text="item.name"></td>
    <td v-text="item.phone_number"></td>
    <td v-text="item.email"></td>
    <td><button @click="fireDelete(item.id)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Below is an excerpt from my Vue component.

```
data() {
      return {
        items: []
      }
    },

methods: {
    fireDelete(id) {
        axios.delete('/item/'+id).then();
    }
},
mounted() {
      axios.get('/item').then(response => this.items = response.data);
    }
```

The axios.get work and so does the axios.delete, but the fronend doesn't react so the item is only removed from the table after a page refresh. How do I get it to remove the relevant `<tr>`?

Comment: you want the `tr` removed or the `td` ?

Comment: The `<tr>` as each one represents a database table row. After I remove the row from the DB I also want to remove the corresponding `<tr>`

Comment: If your `organisations` items aren't dynamically linked to your database, the frontend will never update. Two solutions: find a way to link them, or remove the item in the `organisations` array in `fireDelete` method.

Comment: Sorry, edited the code. organisations = items. 

I am trying to remove an item from the array, after I delete the record from the DB but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to work out a nice way. I pass the index to the fireDelete method and use the splice function. Works exactly how I wanted.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="(item, index) in items" v-bind:index="index">
    <td v-text="item.name"></td>
    <td v-text="item.phone_number"></td>
    <td v-text="item.email"></td>
    <td><button @click="fireDelete(item.id, index)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>


fireDelete(id, index) {
        axios.delete('/item/'+id).then(response => this.organisations.splice(index, 1));
      }
```

Comment: what is the function of index?

Comment: To know which item in the array to 'splice' aka remove. Splice takes the array index as parameter

Comment: Unsure where organisations come from.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same trouble as this question. So maybe someone will find this usefull.

For the `button` use:

```
v-if="items.length > 1" v-on:click="fireDelete(index)"
```

And the `fireDelete` function:

```
fireDelete: function (index) { 
    this.photos.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Comment: Unsure where the photos come from.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to modify your `@click="fireDelete(item.id)"` part to a custom method `@click='deleteData(items, item.id)'`

and do something like:

```
methods: {
  deleteData (items, id) {
    this.items = null // These parts may not 
    this.fireDelete(id) // match your exact code, but I hope
  }                     // you got the idea.
}
```

and your template can do just:

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="item in items" v-if='items'>
   <td v-text="item.name"></td>
   <td v-text="item.phone_number"></td>
   <td v-text="item.email"></td>
   <td><button @click="deleteData(item,  item.id)">Delete</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: If I set items to `null` wouldn't that get rid of every row?

Comment: It will, actually thats what I too had in mind when I asked you if you want the row or td removed. I dont see how you got access to items in your code. You just have organisations in your data. If you add that, I can help with particular item being removed.

Comment: yes, I only want to remove the row on which the delete button was clicked

Comment: Do multiple rows have access to `items`? If not, then this solution works fine, else I need to edit.